# Google Document - Background Color

Tags: document, google-docs, google-apps-script

How can the background color of a document element be removed (aka set to null)?

I've tried setting the value to "null", however, the system gives me this error:
"We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 14)"

*If I comment line 14 (activeSel.setBackgroundColor) out the script works fine*

```
function clearDoc(){
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(DOC1Id);
  var activeSel = doc.getActiveSection().getParagraphs()[2];
  var attr = activeSel.getAttributes(); // BACKGROUND_COLOR = "#ff0000"
  activeSel.setBackgroundColor(null); // errors out
  return
}
```

Comment: I tried setAttributes(object) as recommended in the documentation but without any result either...It throws an error Exception : null

Comment: Thanks for taking a look Serge :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting BACKGROUND_COLOR to null (or using `setBackgroundColor`) now clears the background color. The example given above no longer errors out.

Comment: Confirmed that `setBackfroundColor(null)` works perfectly!  Thank you @kacrouse and **Google Apps Script Team**!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the background color to white ("#ffffff")?

Comment: Eric -- Yes, that is my current workaround. That solution, however, doesn't solve the issue. Let's say, for example, your Document's background is an image or other color. The "white" solution would show up. Thanks for the suggestion!  :)

Comment: I see, there is a difference between white and no background, and the UI let's you set it. Please file a feature request on the issue tracker for this. http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list

Comment: Thanks for the support Eric  : )  Posted the feature request: Issue 2101